# List of 2-element lists from first 2 Dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a tab-delimited `.csv`, which I can now open using `sep="\t"`.

```py
import pandas as pd

col_names = ['instance', 'class', 'example']
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep="\t", names=col_names)
```

'test.csv' looks like this:

```
value1 | value2 | value3
...
```

I want a **list** object, that is a list of 2-element long sub-lists. That captures only the first 2 column values. Each sub-list representing a row in the dataframe `df`:

```py
my_list = [ [value1, value2], [value1, value2], [value1, value2] ] # ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select first 2 columns and convert output to `numpy array` and then to `list`:

```
L = df.iloc[:, :2].to_numpy().tolist()
```

Comment: Incredible. Thank you. Short and sweet